# Consquences of demeaning an ordinal variable

Tags: mean, ordinal-data

I have a discrete variable with a scale from 0 (no issue) - 3 (severe issue). Because what constitutes an issue, is really a quite relative concept (especially when comparing different regions), I am considering demeaning this variable by group. This has two advantages:

1. I would argue that is has a better interpretation, because the variable now signals the difference from the mean by group, which I is more informative for my specific situation.
2. The variable is no longer discrete, but continuous (which in my case is a big advantage because I want to instrument this variable icw a control function).

Are there any downsides to this approach, or am I overlooking something important?

I would be very grateful for an authoritative source on this subject.

Comment: What do you want to do afterwards with the "demeaned" variable? Advantages and disadvantages may depend on that. Also, whether measuring relative to a group mean rather than on an overall scale is appropriate depends on what the groups are, and what kind of interpretation you want to give the outcomes of whatever you want to do with the data. So how good an argument (1) is really depends on what exactly the data are. Some analyses allow interpretation relative to the group without demeaning first.

Comment: Argument (2) is a misconception. "Continuous" is not the opposite of ordinal, but of discrete. After demeaning, your values are still discrete, because in each group they can only take a small number of values. Ordinality regards the information content of a variable, which is not quantitative but only concerns the order. This doesn't change with demeaning. If you have variables taking values 1,2,3,4, "ordinality" means that the difference between 1 and 2 cannot be taken as quantitatively the same as the difference between 2 and 3, for example. This doesn't change after subtracting a mean.

Comment: Transforming original values 1,2,3,4 to -1.2, -0.2, 0.8, 1.8, say, doesn't make them continuous, and neither does it make information content quantitative that before was not quantitative.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. With respect to your second comment. You are absolutely right (changed that). And I also agree with your interpretation.

Comment: With respect, to your last comment. The point is that the mean with respect to the groups is continuous. By subtracting these means from the original values, therefore also makes the new variable have a continuous distribution.

Comment: With respect to your first comment. I want to instrument that variable. So the variable is a dependent variable in the first stage, and an independent variable in the second. With regard to the interpretation, I am concluding that it makes sense for me (I am not in doubt about that aspect, just the consequences of demeaning)

Comment: That's an interesting point and really depends on my first comment, namely what you want to do with the demeaned data. Most people use demeaned data to do something that doesn't involve the distribution of the mean, i.e., conditions on it, and then data are still as discrete as before. Also, even though the mean is "more continuous" than the original data, for given sample size it can only take finitely many values, so is technically still discrete. (This regards your previous comment.)

Comment: I should say that I'm not against treating ordinal data as interval scaled, or discrete ordinal data as continuous in principle. Neither am I saying that what you want to do is wrong. It may make sense. However, the idea that demeaning somehow allows you to do this and it would not have been allowed before is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I should have probably said. I can treat is as continuous, because my sample size is quite large (n=23,000).

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on : "However, the idea that demeaning somehow allows you to do this and it would not have been allowed before is wrong" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122807/discussion-between-lewian-and-tom).